# assembly moving a value of over FF to word array

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am trying to find frequency of symbols within text. Whenever I move `ax` the `freq` array a value above ff the value doesn't enter correctly.

Picture of the arr before ff(when ax is ff):

[image: Snapshot]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EpUB.png

Picture of the arr after ff(after another loop wgen ax is 100):

[image]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmMEk.png

My assmbler is tasm within dosbox eumlutor/

```
proc ChkFreq
; get frequency list
;1. amount of characters in file
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax
push cx
push dx
mov cx,[bp+4]
xor ax,ax
mov di,offset Freq
chk:
    xor bx,bx
    call FillBuffer
    mov bl,[Buffer]
    shl bx,1;not sure if this line is correct but it doesn't affect the problem
    add bx,di
    mov ax,[bx]
    inc ax
    mov [bx],ax
loop chk
pop dx
pop cx
pop ax
pop bp 
ret
endp ChkFreq
```

Thanks in advance Doron

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.. 0xFF + 1 *is* 0x100.

Comment: after another loop 100 did not   move correctly into the array.Not like ff that did move correctly,

Comment: How did you conclude that _"100 did not move correctly into the array"_? In the second image, 0x100 can be seen at address `ds:00FC`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, i didnt know well enough how word arrays work so i thought this should look diffrent. Sorry to bother you and thanks.

Comment: `shl bx,1` is correct for word array, it's multiplying char value by two, because each word is 2 bytes long (ie. for value `0`  the first word in array is at offsets +0 and +1, for value `1` it's +2 and +3, ...).